# My encryption method works using EVP function in openssl.h however decryption fails with the following error::rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt

Tags: rsa

My RSA decryption function implemented in C fails with a padding check error, i have tried changing the input buffer size, but it still fails. I don't know what i'm doing wrong:
Most solutions say that the problem is with input buffer (it should be key size minus padding overhead) i have tried doing that it still fails
When i try decrypting the encrypted file using command-line openssl utilitty, decryption works fine which confirms that my encryption function works. Encryption works using 128-bit chunk size.
THis is the error i receive:

C002E9DB1C790000:error:0200009F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error:crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:269:
C002E9DB1C790000:error:02000072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed:crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:499:

```
/**
 * alice - decryption function
 * @fpath: plaintext filepath
 * @pkey: pubkey path
 *
 */

#include "abdo.h"

#define OUTPUT "decrypt.bin"


int alice(char *fpath, char *pkey)
{
    FILE *out;
    FILE *in;
    FILE *key;
    unsigned char *debuf;
    unsigned char *enbuf;
    size_t delen;
    size_t enlen;
    EVP_PKEY *prik;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;



    /**
     * open pkey
     */
    key = fopen(pkey, "rb");
    if(!key)
    {
        puts("Failed to read pri-key file");
        return (1);
    }
    
    /**
     * read the key
     */
    prik = PEM_read_PrivateKey(key, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    fclose(key); //we no longer need it
    if(!prik)
    {
        puts("Error reading pri-key");
        return (1);
    }
    /**
     * set up encryption context
     */
    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(prik, NULL);
    if (!ctx)
    {
        puts("Failed to set up encryption context!!");
        EVP_PKEY_free(prik);
        return (1);
    }
    /**
     * initialize the context
     */
    if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx) <= 0)
    {
        puts("Context init failed!!");
        EVP_PKEY_free(prik);
        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
        return (1);
    }
    /**
     * set padding scheme
     */
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0)
    {
        puts("Failed to set padding!!");
        EVP_PKEY_free(prik);
        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
        return (1);
    }

    /**
     * allocating needed memory
     */
    enbuf = (unsigned char *)errmalloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (EVP_PKEY_size(prik)- 10));

    /**
     * decryption
     */
    //First we open the files
    in = ispath(fpath, "rb");
    out = ispath(OUTPUT, "wb");
    enlen = fread(enbuf, sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof(unsigned char) * (EVP_PKEY_size(prik) - 10), in);
    if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, NULL, &delen, enbuf, strlen((char *)enbuf)) <= 0)
    {
        puts("Determining size error");
        handleErrors();
        EVP_PKEY_free(prik);
        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
        fclose(in);
        fclose(out);
        free(enbuf);
        return (1);
    }
    debuf = OPENSSL_malloc(delen);
    if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, debuf, &delen, enbuf, strlen((char *)enbuf)) <= 0)
    {
        puts("Decryption error!!");
        handleErrors();
        EVP_PKEY_free(prik);
        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
        fclose(in);
        fclose(out);
        free(enbuf);
        return (1);
    }
    fwrite(debuf, sizeof(unsigned char), delen, out);
    bzero(enbuf, EVP_PKEY_size(prik));
    

    /**
     * Success
     * Release all resources
     */
    EVP_PKEY_free(prik);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
    free(enbuf);
    free(debuf);
    puts("Success");
    return (0);
}
```